# UIView: how does the appearance() proxy work?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiappearance

I have created a simple custom `UIView`:

```
final class TestView: UIView {
    var testColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = testColor
        }
    }
}
```

Then I wrote this in my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testView: TestView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testView2: TestView!        
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3) {
            TestView.appearance().testColor = .red
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this, I get an error:

[image]

Could you help me understanding what's wrong here and how to implement the `UIAppearance` proxy for any custom `UIView`?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the screenshot. Then people answering the question will be able to quote the text or suggest corrections to it. Text will be able to be found through search. As it stands now, your screenshots make it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the property `@objc` and `dynamic`:

```
final class TestView: UIView {
    @objc dynamic var testColor: UIColor? = .white {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = testColor
        }
    }
}
```

Worth noting: the `UIAppearance` proxy does **NOT** affect views which are already part of the view hierarchy.

So, in your example, adding `@objc dynamic` to your property will get rid of the crash, but you will **not** see any change to the two `@IBOutlet` views.

If you call it as part of `viewDidLoad()` (instead of `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TestView.appearance().testColor = .red
}
```

The two `@IBOutlet` views **will** get the red background.

Or, if you add a new view to the hierarchy, it will get the red background:

```
class AppearanceTestViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testView: TestView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testView2: TestView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3) {
            TestView.appearance().testColor = .red
            self.addAnotherTestView()
        }
    }
    func addAnotherTestView() -> Void {
        let v = TestView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor),
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])

        // this newly added view WILL have a red background
    }
}
```

Comment: Very simple in fact, thank you!